# POST method throws net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, backend

I have my frontend on reactJS. I want to send data from my react to PHP backend, which will then push data to mySQL database. Everything is working fine on localhost (using xxamp).

I want to now publish my web site to be available all the time, so I decided to use 000webhost. I pushed my PHP files into it's htdocs folder, and also created MySQL database on 000webhost.

However, when I try to send data from my react to PHP backend, I get the error:

> net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is my frontend code:

```
    const url = 'https://scandiwebirakli2.000webhostapp.com/addProduct.php'; // Replace with your API endpoint
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: data // The JSON data you want to send
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json(); // If you expect a JSON response from the server
      })
      .then(data => {
        // Handle the response from the server
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle any errors
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
```

Also my PHP code:

```php
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$skuData = json_decode($data, true);

if ($skuData !== null) {

    $servername = "placeholder";
    $username = "placeholder";
    $password = "placeholder.";
    $dbname = "placeholder";
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sku = $skuData['sku'];
        $name = $skuData['name'];
        $price = $skuData['price'];
        $sizeMB = $skuData['sizeMB'];
        $height = $skuData['height'];
        $width = $skuData['width'];
        $length = $skuData['length'];
        $weight = $skuData['weight'];

        // Create a prepared statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO products (sku, name, price, sizeMB, height, width, length, weight) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

        // Bind the parameters and execute the statement
        $stmt->execute([$sku, $name, $price, $sizeMB, $height, $width, $length, $weight]);

        echo "Data inserted successfully!";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo 'Invalid data received from the client.';
}
exit()
?>
```

Any idea what might be causing `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` Error?

NOTE: I tried refreshing cookies, browser data, using other browsers, using axios too. Nothing helped...